# Loading in XML file with Javascript in Internet Explorer 10 not working

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-10, selectsinglenode

I'm loading in an XML file with javascript using the code below. The problem I'm having is with Internet Explorer 10 alone, it's working in every other browser.

After some research I'm quite confident it's the fact that IE10 dropped "selectSingleNode" compatibility, but I just can't figure out a work around. Any tips on how get this working in IE10? Thanks.

```
// LOAD LANGUAGE XML
$.ajax({
    url: '/bnt/res/xml/lng_'+ lng.toUpperCase() +'.xml',
    success: function(r) {
        var xLng = r.selectSingleNode('//language');
        site.search.data.appendChild(xLng);
        site.parseLanguage(site.search.data);
        site.post_xml_load();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `getElementsByTagName` and iterating over the results instead?